# How to verify date format using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-rc

How can I verify that a date displayed on the web page fits a particular format with Python bindings for Selenium-RC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would grab the date (using whatever selector is appropriate), then try to parse it with Python's [`strftime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime). If the parser raises an exception the date is likely incorrect.

Comment: can you give an example.cos i'm title new to python.grab means getiing the content(date value) using get_value right??

Comment: and do you know how to access class using selenium.becouse class contains font size,bgcolor etc i need to verify those attributes.thanks for ur replay buddy.

Comment: I don't know off the top of my head, but I'm quite certain you can find those from googling, or from asking more StackOverflow questions.

Comment: thx for your replay and can you give an example to ur answer?grab means getiing the content(date value) using get_value right??

Comment: Sorry, yes, using `get_value` (or possibly `get_text`) is what I mean. Also, I'm really not sure what you'd need an example for — it's literrally two function calls: `date_str = sel.get_text("…selector…")` and `datetime.strftime("…format…", date_str)`.